# Can I skip cmake compiler tests or avoid "error: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'"

Tags: c, cmake, cross-compiling

compilation options for cmake (on windows) for ARM target system but when I run configure it's starting compiler tests:

```
CMake Error at D:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (MESSAGE):
  The C compiler "D:/Program Files/yagarto/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" is not
  able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: D:/merge/complex/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:D:/PROGRA~1/YAGART~1/bin/make.exe "cmTryCompileExec/fast"

  D:/PROGRA~1/YAGART~1/bin/make.exe -f
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/build

  make.exe[1]: Entering directory
  `D:/merge/complex/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  "D:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report
  D:/merge/complex/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1

  Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

  "D:/Program Files/yagarto/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
  D:/merge/complex/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

  Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec

  "D:/Program Files/yagarto/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe"
  "CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o" -o cmTryCompileExec
  -rdynamic 

  arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: error: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'

  make.exe[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec] Error 1
```

Using Yagatdo 4.6.* cross-compilation toolchain

How can I skip this tests or fix -rdynamic error that I am getting?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can skip the compiler checks by adding `NONE` to your `project` call:

```
project(<projectname> NONE)
```

but this can have pretty far-reaching effects.  For full details, run

```
cmake --help-command project
```

I'm not familiar with ARM, so this is probably not your best option here.  I guess you'd be better to see if there's a way to fix the `-rdynamic` flag.

#### EDIT:

It looks like this was [identified as a bug](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=9985) which is effectively still unresolved.  The comments in the bug report mention adding the following lines as a workaround (presumably before your `project` call):

```
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_C_FLAGS "")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_CXX_FLAGS "")
```

Comment: so yagarto is most sane arm compiler afaik, I don't understand why "simple program" request this special.

Comment: @Sholy I just updated the answer - hope this fixes it for you.

Comment: I see but I'm getting same output with this sadly :(

Comment: @Sholy - OK, here's my last guess :-)  Try looking at [this thread](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Errors-using-CMAKE-for-cross-compiling-td6472536.html), but note that the settings should be done before the `project` call.

Comment: to be honest it's still trying to test... but thank you now I think I have enough info for research.

Comment: The best answer is found below: set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)

Comment: These other answers should be cleaned out as they are obsolete and create confusion.

Comment: @natersoz The answer that you refer to recommends to skip the tests. If someone is cross-compiling they don't necessarily want to skip the tests. They might only want to prevent the addition of the `-rdynamic` flag. The answers together sketch the most complete picture.

Answer (score 42):

You can set `CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_WORKS` to true to suppress further compiler checks for that language.

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
```

Comment: You may also need to add a matching "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS" line.  This worked for me in a case where for a particular cross-compilation target CMake insisted on using the wrong library path and failed to link the test executable, but picked up the right path for real builds.

Answer (score 28):

It seems you target actually something else than Linux, so you should tell cmake that you are cross-compiling for the generic case:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
```

Followed by (optionally, but nice to specify):

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
SET(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING 1)
```

However, if you specify (which you likely did because this is stated in a lot of examples online):

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
```

Then cmake will load the configuration files from (suppose version 2.8) the file:

```
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Platform/Linux.cmake
```

from which it is likely to load:

```
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Platform/Linux-GNU.cmake
```

Here the `-rdynamic` flag is set for historical reasons:

```
macro(__linux_compiler_gnu lang)
  # We pass this for historical reasons.  Projects may have
  # executables that use dlopen but do not set ENABLE_EXPORTS.
  set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_${lang}_FLAGS "-rdynamic")
endmacro()
```

Rather than disabling the tests as indeed is done by specifying `NONE` as the `PROJECT` argument, it seems setting the `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` (to something else than `Linux`, for instance `Generic`) is what you actually want to do.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. The trouble with setting CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_C_FLAGS is that `-rdynamic` is added even when we're just linking an executable with no shared libraries involved. But changing the system name to something other than Linux worked.

Answer (score 7):

If you're just compiling a static library and you want to avoid having CMake test that the compiler can generate binaries, you can set the variable [`CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE.html).

```
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 1):

When cross compiling for Windows, where there is no -rdynamic option, you can use

```
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME="Windows"
```

with cmake. Then Cmake will skip the test with -rdynamic.