# How to statically allocate memory based upon type information from another translation unit

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a bunch of complex classes in one translation unit which involves a bunch of header dependencies. In addition, the translation unit provides a factory function.

```
// MyClass.h

#include "Interface.h"
// lots of other includes

class MyClass : public Interface {
  // lots of members
}:

// Creates an instance of MyClass using placement new
Interface* createMyClassAt(uint8_t* location);
```

In another translation unit I want to use multiple instances of different classes deriving from `Interface` and I want to allocate them in static memory. It's a small embedded system without heap. I want to avoid the inclusion of `MyClass.h` because some its dependencies are internal.

```
// somefile.cpp
#include "Interface.h"

extern Interface* createMyClassAt(uint8_t* location);

uint8_t myClassContainer[sizeofMyClass];

int main() {
    createMyClassAt(myClassContainer);
    // more stoff
}
```

My understanding is, that it is impossible to determine `sizeofMyClass` without having the actual type information of `MyClass`. No matter what I do. I cannot get this information across translation units.

How to achieve my goal then? Do I need to go via the build system and extract the sizes somehow from the object files and generate a header from that? That might be OK after all.

Edit 1: Some clarification:

- All those classes derived from Interface.h are defined in a prelinked, self-contained static library at the end.
- By "internal dependencies" I mean other header files and types that I don't want to leak to consumers of the library
- The consumers of the library may create multiple instances of various classes.

Comment: Why not to define this array in compilation unit where type is defined?

Comment: Why not use PIMPL to hide the internal dependencies and expose the class?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk PIMPL can be prohibitively expensive in embedded.

Comment: Can you try C++20 Modules?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk I cannot use C++ 20 modules, unfortunately and PIMPL won't help because it relies on heap.

Comment: I'm not sure you can deduce this size, but you could hack this by defining a constant which is the size you think `sizeofMyClass` will be, and then add a `static_assert` in the actual class definition that checks if the constant is correct. It won't be portable (at least not without tweaking the constant for the given platform) but at least it will work and will always be "correct".

Comment: @Slava because I may need to create multiple instances of the type. The actual number is not known to the type.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux so your suggestion is to defer correct allocation to the developer who would - by the help of the compiler - need to figure out the container size by trial and error?

Comment: @RichardW It doesn't sound great, but it is the only thing I can think of that doesn't involve an external tool, given the requirements. I believe C++ just doesn't support what you want to do. Maybe the solution is to look at removing the inclusion of the internals dependencies from the class headers (though I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that).

Comment: `want to avoid the inclusion of MyClass.h because some its dependencies are internal.` that is odd. So don't include dependencies, only the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to achieve my goal then?

Approuch 1: static assert and "gueess" sizes. There is no dependency between `interface.h` and the class, but you have to *manually* update the header on each change (or, better, generate the header from the build system).

```
// interface.h
using Interface_storage = std::aligned_storage<20, 16>;
//                                              ^^^^^^ - size and alignment
// They are _hard-coded_ here and _need_ to be _manually_ updated each time
// MyClass changes.
Interface* createMyClassAt(Interface_storage& location);

// interface.c
Interface* createMyClassAt(Interface_storage& location) {
   // static assertion check
  static_assert(sizeof(MyClass) == sizeof(Interface_storage) &&
     alignof(MyClass) == alignof(Interface_storage), 
    " Go and fix the header file");
  // use placement new on location
}

// main.c
int main() {
  Interface_storage storage;    // nice&clean
  Interface *i = createMyClassAt(storage);
  destroyMyClassAt(i, storage);
}
```

Approuch 2: Unix systems since the ages used file descriptors. A file descriptor is simple - it's just an index in an array of... somethings. It's trivial to implement, and you can hide *everything* behind a single integer value. That basically means, that you have to use dynamic memory, or you have to know in advance how many objects you need and allocate memory for all of them.

The below pseudocode implementation just returns the pointer to the interface, but it's very similar to returning an index in the array just like file descriptors.

```
// interface.h
Interface *new_MyClass();
destroy_MyClass(Interface *);

// interface.c
#define MAX 5
std::array<std::aligned_storage<sizeof(MyClass), alignof(MyClass)>, MAX> arr;
std::array<bool, MAX> used;

Interface *new_MyClass() {
   // find the fist not used and return it.
   for (size_t i = 0; i < used.size(); ++i) {
      if (!used[i]) {
         used[i] = true;
         return new(arr[i]) MyClass();
       }
   }
   return nullptr;
}

void destroy_MyClass(Interface *i) {
   // update used array and destroy
}
```

Comment: Something similar to solution 1 was also suggested by @François Andrieux further up. I prefer to allocate the storage manually in main.c though and to submit the container as a span to the creator function. I think that's simple enough. I am leaning towards accepting this as an answer.

Approach 2 has the drawback that my library needs to preallocate a guessed max number of instances and the linker is not able to throw the unused memory away.

Comment: If you set up generating the header from the build system, it's just.... it just works. You should also make `createMyClassAt` return a `std::unique_ptr` with a custom destructor, so that you don't have to remember about it.

Comment: You may be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69950658/setting-maximum-static-alignment-in-eigen-from-cmake/69952705#69952705  as to how to cross-compile and still get stuff from the compiler without ever running executable..

Comment: that's a smart idea.

Answer (score 1):

Make a second function which returns the size of your class:

```
extern size_t sizeofMyClass();


size_t sizeofMyClass() { return sizeof(MyClass); }
```

If you want it at compile time, than `constexpr` it.

Comment: To declare a global array, you need to know the size at compile time. To get that you'd need to include the header that defines the class (it can't be a function in a different source file), so this doesn't really change anything from what OP is needing to do now.

Comment: The size returned by this function cannot be used to statically allocate storage in another translation unit. It's not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `myClassContainer` in the "someFile" translation unit but actually define it in the "myClass" translation unit. This can be made easier with a common header file:

```cpp
// globaldefs.h
#include <cstdint>

extern std::uint8_t myClassContainer[];
#ifdef MY_CLASS_DEFINED
alignas(MyClass) std::uint8_t myClassContainer[sizeof(MyClass)];
#endif
```

```cpp
// MyClass.h
class MyClass : public Interface {
  // lots of members
};

#define MY_CLASS_DEFINED
#include "globaldefs.h"
```

```cpp
// somefile.cpp
#include "globaldefs.h"

extern Interface* createMyClassAt(uint8_t* location);

int main() {
    createMyClassAt(myClassContainer);
    // more stuff
}
```

That way, the translation unit with `somefile.cpp` only sees `std::uint8_t myClassContainer[];`, and no size is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a second attempt to answer the question.

You cannot do what you want. The only reason to hide the implementation (PIMPL) is to allow you to compile the module completely independently.
You cannot do this, whilst at the same time as injecting a dependency. What you ask for is self-contradictory.

Either declare the class in the header, so that the dependency is declared, or put the array in the module that contains the class. If its a static array, why does it matter which module it is declared in.

In other words, use a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern), accessible via a free-function