# How to extract the size of a type from a binary without running or using special tools

Tags: c++, templates

I want to extract the size of certain types from an object file / library

- without running the binary
- without special tools
- for any toolchain (GNU, MSVC, IAR)

I'd like to follow the approach [presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69950658/setting-maximum-static-alignment-in-eigen-from-cmake/69952705#69952705), but in a more generic form.

Ideally it would work like this:

```cpp
// Some file.cpp
class MyClass {
    // lots of members
};

#include "SizeInfo.h"
const SizeInfo<MyClass, "MyIdentifier"> info;
```

I would put `SizeInfo` anywhere I am interested in the size of a type. I might be interested in multiple types per translation unit. The solution should put the string `SizeOf MyIdentifier:1234` into the resulting object file so that I can extract both identifier and size using a simple tool like grep. It is expected that the variable is thrown out of the resulting executable or a shared library because it's not used anywhere.

I am using boost in my project, so if that would simplify the implementation, I am all for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be possible to simply get the size of the type with a regular `sizeof` and then convert the number to a string as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999573/convert-a-number-to-a-string-literal-with-constexpr) via variadic templates.

Then you can export a string variable from your object file and grep for it on the outside.

It should work something like this:
SizeInfo.h:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<unsigned... digits>
    struct to_chars { static const char value[]; };

    template<unsigned... digits>
    constexpr char to_chars<digits...>::value[] = {('0' + digits)..., 0};

    template<unsigned rem, unsigned... digits>
    struct explode : explode<rem / 10, rem % 10, digits...> {};

    template<unsigned... digits>
    struct explode<0, digits...> : to_chars<digits...> {};
}

template<unsigned num>
struct num_to_string : detail::explode<num> {};
```

I downloaded the header file `static_string.hpp` from [this excellent tutorial on static strings](https://github.com/akrzemi1/static_string).

Some file.cpp:

```
class MyClass {
    // lots of members
};

#include "static_string.hpp"
namespace sstr = ak_toolkit::static_str;

#include "Sizeinfo.h"
constexpr auto MyClassSize = "MyIdentifier: " + sstr::literal(num_to_string<sizeof(MyClass)>::value);
```

After compiling with `gcc -c Somefile.cpp` I can validate the following string inside the object file: `MyIdentifier: 8`.

Comment: Is 'MyClassSize' assembled at compile time?

Comment: You're right. It's not. I have to see how to make it happen. Give me a minute.

Comment: I succeeded! I will edit my answer.

Comment: Done! Please validate the updated information, my test succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

This gives the size of a type in bytes:

```
sizeof(MyClass)
```