# Cannot run simple program using std::filesystem

Tags: arm, filesystems, cross-compiling, arm64, exiv2

When I compile exiv2 using the compilation chain aarch64-linux-gnu-g++, I get the following error,

```
-- Looking for C++ include filesystem
-- Looking for C++ include filesystem - found
-- Performing Test CXX_FILESYSTEM_NO_LINK_NEEDED
-- Performing Test CXX_FILESYSTEM_NO_LINK_NEEDED - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_FILESYSTEM_STDCPPFS_NEEDED
-- Performing Test CXX_FILESYSTEM_STDCPPFS_NEEDED - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_FILESYSTEM_CPPFS_NEEDED
-- Performing Test CXX_FILESYSTEM_CPPFS_NEEDED - Failed
CMake Error at cmake/FindFilesystem.cmake:248 (message):
  Cannot run simple program using std::filesystem
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/findDependencies.cmake:41 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:95 (include)
```

I wrote a demo to test filesystem on arm, it works fine, and when I compile exiv2 without using the compilation chain, there is no such error

The build options I added in cmakelists are,

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

Comment: See also: [Cmake compile a simple program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633705/cmake-the-c-compiler-is-not-able-to-compile-a-simple-test-program).  The issue is that cmake is trying to run the code on the build machine, but the build machine doesn't have the same packages as the target.  This is a common option with cross compiling/building and systems like CMake.

Comment: You should write a toolchain file.